# Syncing two or more Calendars

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar

I have one calendar in my site and under this site, there are four and five sub sites. each sub site will have one calendar.

I want to display all the events(which are there in sub sites) in my main site calendar.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in SP 2010 OOTB.  Go to the main calendar and click on the left where is says calendars in view.  Here you can add additional calendars even from other sites and choose what color they display as on the main calendar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, can't we merge the events? let me explain you in detail an event is added in sub site calendar, the changes need to be displayed in site calendar automatically.

Comment: If you want a no code solution then the method given by Steve above fits your requirements. It will just take a little management to link the root site with the sub-site calendars. If you want something more complex you will need to either use a workflow (if events need approval) or event receivers.

Comment: What you described will happen with the solution I submitted.  As soon as an item is added to a sub-site calendar, if you have it connected to the main calendar, then that event will instantly show up on the main calendar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, can't we merge the all events into single calendar i.e main site calendar? let me explain you in detail an event is added in sub site calendar, the changes need to be displayed in site calendar automatically.

Comment: You mean through calendar overlay settings?

Comment: Yes, that's it!